# Solution to the Yule Walker Equation

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

**Problem:** For an AR(p) process,

$X_t = b_0 + b_1X_{t-1} + ... + b_pX_{t-p} + \varepsilon_t$

the Yule Walker equation takes the form

$\gamma(k) - b_1\gamma(k-1) - b_2\gamma(k-2) - ... - b_p\gamma(k-p) = 0$

I wish to show that the solution takes the form

$\gamma(k) = c_1\alpha_1^{-k} + ... + c_p\alpha_p^{-k}$

where $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_p$ are the roots of the characteristic function $b(x)$ for the AR(p) process and are assumed to be distinct.

**Attempt:** I am given the hint that since $b(B)\gamma(k) = (1-\alpha_1B)...(1-\alpha_pB)\gamma(k) = 0$, one of $(1-\alpha_jB)\gamma(k)=0$. Note that $B$  is the backshift operator.

So suppose that I follow the hint, then I get $(1-\alpha_jB)\gamma(k)=0 \Rightarrow \gamma(k) = \alpha_j\gamma(k-1)$ for some $j$. I can then substitute this back into the Yule Walker equation to get:

$\gamma(k) - \frac{b_1}{\alpha_j}\gamma(k) - b_2\gamma(k-2) - ... - b_p\gamma(k-p) = 0$.

I can't figure out how to proceed from here.